# XPages Bootstrap DatePicker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, xpages, datapicker, lotus-notes

How can I show the time value for xpages bootstrap datapicker?

I passed this values to the control of Mark Leusnik: http://bootstrap4xpages.com/bs4xp/demos.nsf/datePicker.xsp

```
return {
    daysOfWeekDisabled: "0,6",
    autoclose: true,
    picktime: true,
    todayBtn: "linked",
    language: "es",
    todayHighlight: true
}
```

I want to change the initial day of week, starting on Monday.

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Set Monday as week start with option `weekStart: "1"` (0 = Sunday, 1 = Monday, ...).

There is no option for time value. It is a date picker only. A description of all options you can find [here](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/).